Extracting information from a large volume of pdf files
I have a folder which contains around 4,000 pdf files of news stories, articles, stock market reports, etc, some have several hundred pages,  around 4GB overall.
I have a list of 20 company names
I have to find all references to new shares of these companies coming onto the market, either new shares being issued and sold, or lock-ups on existing investors being waived
I would not expect to find many references
Can I write code or a script to use AI to search these pdf files?
I've seen there are software ai packages that work on one file at a time
